# cordova: App.messageChannel We seem to be missing some stuff :(

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am new in apache cordova. I am using cordova in visual studio 2013.
when i execute application in Ripple-Nexus it show popup as shown in pic
(we seem to be missing some stuff :( )

Please tell me what is messing
[image]

Here is my application code

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ripple some plugins don't work.
Try on a real device .

Comment: when i try to inspect element in browse gets close.please tell ??

Comment: You can inspect/ debug from the real device by connecting with chrome:

More Tools / Developper tools
Then 
Mote Tools / Inspect devices: you should see your app with index.html

Comment: how could i inspect in real device?

Comment: With Chrome like I said above. Or with  Safari if you have a mac.